# Avoiding indexing error when referencing next index while iterating

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

So I have a pandas dataframe and I'm using iterrows() to iterate over each row do some complex stuff to it. Part of this involves subtracting the current's row's coordinates from the next's row's coordinates, so I do

```
sqrt(((row[5] - df.iloc[index+1, 5])**2) + ((row[4] - df.iloc[index+1, 4])**2)) < .1
```

The problem is when I finish iterating over all the rows, the last row will give me an indexing error, because I will be referencing the next index which is nonexistent. I'm thinking of just adding a dummy row onto the end of the dataframe. Is there a more elegant solution to fix this problem?

Edit:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[8] < 10 and sqrt(((row[5] - df.iloc[index+1, 5])**2) + ((row[4] - df.iloc[index+1, 4])**2)) < .1
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Use `shift` instead of index+1.

Comment: You can check if `i == total_number_of_rows-1`, and if so, use `df.iloc[index, ..]` instead of `df.iloc[index+1, ..]`. Otherwise, you do `df.iloc[index+1, ..]`

Comment: @Scott Boston So it's just df.shift.iloc[index, 5]?

Comment: Can you add more complete code the question, how is index defined?

Comment: Edited above. The index is from iterrows().

Comment: 'df.shift(-1).iloc[index,5]`

Comment: But why even use iterrows() at this point? Just define the mask above with a single calculation and `.shift(-1)` and then `#do stuff` dependent upon the mask

Comment: @ALollz I agree... but we'd have to analyze the entire code to make the appropriate changes.

Comment: @ScottBoston Fair point :D

Answer (score 0):

when row is last row your code tried to access a (row+1) which is not present, that's why you are getting indexing error.

run a loop to iterate over all rows except last row, then when your code reaches to second last row it will access last row.

try this code

```
for i in range(len(df.index)-1):           #runs from row 0 to n-2 rows if total rows are n
    # your code
    sqrt(((row[5] - df.iloc[index+1, 5])**2) + ((row[4] - df.iloc[index+1, 4])**2)) < .1
```